# HELP ME WITH BITCOIN TIME STAMPS

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, lost-bitcoins, timestamp, recover-private-key

OK, so I had several backed up .dat files on google which I put in opentimestamps

I could see that these files had time stamp data...   so I uploaded and *****below is what the results were.

What does all this mean?

I just want the bitcoins that I know I have.  I had a wallet.dat from a gui miner I downloded on my pc in 2012.  This has been a nightmare.  I am willing to offer a % of the BTC to anyone who can actually help me.  And no python...  That just has frustrated me beyond my limits.  I have over 50k private keys even more addresses.  My Bitcoin Core Wallet was on my pc since 2012.  I have not run a full node and have since lost access to that pc as it crashed.  I have all the backups...  anyhow..  my question (sense the frustration yet?)

****** What do I do with this? Please use as much lamen terms as possible.  Talk to me as if I am in intro to bitcoin in the 5th grade...

Timestamp of d800xxxxxxx7
Document digest (SHA256): d80XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx6

Download this timestamp

Return to upload page

d800XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxb6 SHA256(Document)
d800aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxef
Append(a4a414...)
92bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxa
SHA256()
Fork into 3 paths
Fork
1 92bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx9
Append(dbf1cf...)
1 f2d4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
SHA256()
1 5f030XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
Prepend(5f0304...)
1 5f03XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx4a
Append(1360d4...)
1 Pending attestation: server https://alice.btc.calendar.opentimestamps.org
Attestation
2 92XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx355
Append(e229a8...)
2 9f8XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SHA256()
2 6XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXcecdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX62
Prepend(625692...)
2 c00XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX44
SHA256()
2 5f0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX44
Prepend(5f0304...)
2 5fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX32
Append(9dd925...)
2 Pending attestation: server https://bob.btc.calendar.opentimestamps.org
Attestation
3 92bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Append(270839...)
3 2XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXf
SHA256()
3 3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX6e34aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX68f
Prepend(3016ec...)
3 1ebeXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SHA256()
3 5f0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxc41
Prepend(5f0304...)
3 5f03XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx16
Append(326fc5...)
3 Pending attestation: server https://finney.calendar.eternitywall.com
Attestation

Comment: When you say "I have over 50k private keys even more addresses", Where do you have these private keys? You can import the private key in many wallets and then you have your Bitcoins.

Answer (score 1):

> OK, so I had several backed up .dat files on google which I put in opentimestamps

Bitcoin core stores wallet data ina file named `wallet.dat` so that was one of your `.dat` files.

Opentimestamps is just a service that provides proof that a document existed on a specific date. It doesn't store the contents of the documents.

You therefore have proof that your `wallet.dat` existed but that is of no use to you.

> I just want the bitcoins that I know I have. I had a wallet.dat

You need to find either

- that `wallet.dat` and any password you used to protect it
- or a written copy of the "private key" that the wallet contained.

Otherwise all the money that was in that wallet is forever lost and unusable.